# How can i download the sources file of website in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

How can i download the sources file of any website into my local pc via chrome dev tools.

See the below img.

[image]

Comment: look it up in the network tab. or use a scraper\

Comment: Why do you want to use the dev tools and not curl, wget, or even just "Save as..." in the browser?

Answer (score -3):

You can download it by right click on a file (not on the folder; every file is under a folder ), and clicking on 'Save As...'.